# Is $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$ a limiting value?

Tags: calculus

When a limiting process is used for an expression (such as gradient)  the value of the expression usually tends to a limiting value, but in the case of $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$ for $f(x)=x$, its value (the value of the expression) does not approach any value but is rather fixed or equal to $1$, in such a case, is $1$ referred to as a limiting value?

Comment: I would say $$f'(x)$$ if the limit exists.

Comment: The mathematical terminology "approaches a limit" is not the same as the natural language meaning. Mathematically speaking, being at the limit is still considered approaching the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the limit of a constant function is that constant value. See, for instance, the limit laws at http://people.math.umass.edu/~gunnells/teaching/Sample_Lecture_Notes.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be considered as a limiting value if you stick to the rigorous definition of a "limit". Indeed for any $\varepsilon >0$, we can choose $1$ so that for any $\Delta x <1$, we have $\Big|\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}-1\Big|=0< \varepsilon $. Then we can say $\lim \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x} =1$.